# .Onion not viewable, apache2 is working

Tags: onion-services

I've been trying to get a hidden service up and running for a while now. I've followed several guides and they all pretty much say the same thing. I've opened up the port that I have apache2 listening to. I can view it on the clearnet so I know that much is working. I've configured the `torrc` file to redirect to my open port also.

But, whenever I try to view my `.onion` in tor browser its always down. I've done `chmod` on the directory so that shouldn't be an issue.

What am I missing here? Someone please help me. I cant get this to work for the life of me. Would be willing to donate to someone who took the time to walk me through this.

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you check the logs?

Comment: Can you post your torrc config for that hidden service? 
And also the log output.
We need more info before we can see what's wrong.

Comment: If your Tor is running on the same host as your web server, make sure the web server (also) listens on localhost, and not only on its ethernet interface(s).